# MySQL Finding min values for multiple rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to be able to access multiple minimum values depending on another column.

For example, a race has multiple laps and I want to know which tap was completed the quickest, but the table Lap has data for multiple races.

```
SELECT MIN(lapTime), lapRaceName, lapRaceDate
FROM Lap JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT raceRaceName
    FROM Race ) races
    ON Lap.lapRaceName = races.raceRaceName
```

This code I have only finds the quickest lap time for all the races combined, not the lap times for individual races.

Thanks!

Comment: group by lapracename;

Comment: And if you're still struggling, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1):

The query is missing a GROUP BY

```
SELECT MIN(Lap.lapTime), Lap.lapRaceName, Lap.lapRaceDate
FROM Lap 
JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT raceRaceName
    FROM Race 
) races
ON races.raceRaceName = Lap.lapRaceName
GROUP BY Lap.lapRaceName, Lap.lapRaceDate
```

But maybe this one could be simplified?
Since it doesn't seem to get any extra data from the sub-query.  The INNER JOIN on the sub-query only seems to assure that the racename also exists in the Race table.

```
SELECT MIN(lapTime) AS MinLapTime, lapRaceName, lapRaceDate
FROM Lap
GROUP BY lapRaceName, lapRaceDate
ORDER BY lapRaceName, lapRaceDate
```

Another thing is that the name of race is also kept in  the Lap table.
According the common practise of normalization it would be better if the Lap table has a foreign key to the primary key of the Race table.
Then the name of the race is kept only in one table.

Then it could be a query like this example:

```
SELECT MIN(Lap.lapTime), Race.raceRaceName, Lap.lapRaceDate
FROM Lap 
JOIN Race
  ON Race.raceID = Lap.lapRaceId
GROUP BY Race.raceID, Race.raceRaceName, Lap.lapRaceDate
```